# How to create "sequin" texture on a shape in Affinity?

Tags: effects, affinity-designer

I would like to mock up a texture so it looks like the design is made out of shiny sequins. It is trivial to get a photo of sequins and use a font or shape to clip them; but then you are left with the hard edges of the font/shape. What I'm looking for is a way to "scatter" one symbol or small image over another, the way you can with particle systems in 3D software, so that it appears the font/shape is formed from sequins. (The result will be tacky, I know, but it's what I need to do.)

Is there any way to accomplish this in either Affinity Designer or Affinity Photo?

PS: I needed to tag this with "affinity-photo"--but that tag does not yet exist. Could someone with a high enough reputation please create it?

Comment: One possibility is to draw like it has been done at least 100 years. To see it search for  videos of drawing  sequin clothes. I guess you expect some help that Affinity Photo and Designer could offer -a way to get plausible shading and glittery with less (skills) that traditional drawing needs. One trick is to use noise. With it you can relatively easily create some glitter and grain which only suggest that there can be sequins, but so small that they cannot be properly seen as individual shapes. An example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oarSo.png You should insert an example of the wanted effect.

Comment: @user287001 Thank you!